# Calling Stored Procedure from Database Context generated by Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

### The goal

I'm using C# + MVC 4 + MySQL and I want to call in my controller a method create by Entity Framework 5 to call a stored procedure.

### The problem

I do not know how to call in my controller the following method, create in `.Context.cs` file, by Entity Framework:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<getProductsListForHome_Result> getProductsListForHome(Nullable<int> inOffer, Nullable<int> categoryId)
{
    var inOfferParameter = inOffer.HasValue ?
        new ObjectParameter("inOffer", inOffer) :
        new ObjectParameter("inOffer", typeof(int));

    var categoryIdParameter = categoryId.HasValue ?
        new ObjectParameter("categoryId", categoryId) :
        new ObjectParameter("categoryId", typeof(int));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<getProductsListForHome_Result>("getProductsListForHome", inOfferParameter, categoryIdParameter);
}
```

### What I have

I already tried this:

```
//
// GET: /Products/
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<getProductsListForHome_Result> products = db.getProductsListForHome(1, 14);

    var test = string.Join(",", (object[])products.ToArray());

    return Content(test);
}
```

And when I access **/Products/ (the Index() method of Products' Controller)**, I see a blank page with this: **MyApp.Models.getProductsListForHome_Result**.

So I ask: what I have to do?

Answer (score -1):

Change Return Content to Return View.

Comment: "The view 'MyApp.Models.getProductsListForHome_Result' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations."

Comment: Do you have a view set up that takes in your entity model?